# Displaying one value for multiple rows in a MultiIndexed dataframe

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I'm interested in presenting the following data in pandas:

```
metric1 | metric 2 || % occurence | total
-----------------------------------------
   A    |    1     ||    20       |  
        |    2     ||    10       |  35
        |    3     ||    5        |
-----------------------------------------
   B    |    1     ||    40       |
        |    2     ||    10       |  65
        |    3     ||    15       |
```

(For text search, I'd describe this as presenting a breakdown of a groupby together with the aggregate values of the outer level of a MultiIndex)

I can create all the columns except for the `total` column: assuming `df` is a flat table like

```
metric1 | metric 2 | percentage 
--------------------------------
   A    |    1     |    20        
   A    |    2     |    10      
   A    |    3     |    5       
   B    |    1     |    40      
   B    |    2     |    10      
   B    |    3     |    15
```

I can get most of what I want using

```
aggregate_df = df.groupby(['metric1', 'metric2']).sum()
```

And I can get the total values using

```
aggregate_df.sum(level=0)
```

My question is, is there any way to display them together in a single DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiple index you can make it and `crosstab`+`stack`

```
pd.crosstab(index=df.metric1,columns=df.metric2,values=df.percentage,aggfunc='sum',margins=True).set_index('All',append=True).iloc[:-1].stack()
Out[59]: 
metric1  All  metric2
A        35   1          20
              2          10
              3           5
B        65   1          40
              2          10
              3          15
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Wow this was awesome, thanks! The only complaint I have is that the ALL column is part of the index instead of a regular column. Do you know if there's any way to make it a regular column?

Comment: adding `.reset_index(level='All')`at the end @A.Wan

Comment: thanks. The downside is that it then prints once per row; I was ultimately hoping to be able to print one value per outer level but not in the index. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: @A.Wan I do not think it is possible, maybe you can try jupyter format the dataframe , but it is only for view as well